# qt c++ send 6 bytes using tcp protocol

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qbytearray, qdatastream

Hi everybody, first of all I'm new on network programming so maybe this is a simple question, but I don't get it. I try to send 6 Bytes to a microcontroller using tcp socket. In order to serialize my data I'm using qdatastream and qbytearray. That's the way I try to do this:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream outputStream(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
outputStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_8);
outputStream << (quint8) 0
             << (quint8) dataMessage.prefix
             << (quint8) dataMessage.paramID
             << (quint32) dataMessage.data;
outputStream.device()->seek(0);
outputStream << (quint8)(buffer.size() - sizeof(quint8));
qDebug() << buffer;
qDebug() << quint32(dataMessage.data);
sock->write(buffer);

if(sock->write(buffer) == -1)
{
    return -1;
}
sock->flush();
```

My struct dataMessage looks like this for example: dataMessage={15,1,9400000} 
Well in my buffer I would expect this Byte sequence "\x06\xF0\x01\x00\x8F\6E\xC0" 

but I always get the following Output "\x06\xF0\x01\x00\x8Fn\xC0".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The sequences are the same, `\x6E` and `n` are equivalent.

Comment: Hi tkausl :) why are both sequences equivalent?? thx for the fast answer

Comment: Because `\x6E` and `n` are equivalent and thats the only difference I can spot in your two sequences.

Comment: then i will accept that :) thx

Comment: If you're asking why `\x6E` and `n` are the same, `6E` is the (hexadecimal) ASCII code for the letter `n`. qDebug seems to only replace unprintable-characters by hex-escape sequences, thats why everything but the `n` is replaced.